# A new primality test for prime of the form $(n^p-1)/(n-1)$ and $(n^p+1)/(n+1)$ when $p>n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

Here is what I observed:

Let $R_{p}$ = $(n^p-1)/(n-1)$ or $(n^p+1)/(n+1)$ when $n$ is a positive integer $> 1$ and $p$ a prime number $> 2$ and $p > n$.

$R_{p}\text{  is a prime iff: } \ s_{p} \equiv s_{1} \pmod{R_{p}}$ when $s_{1}$ = $p^n$ and $s_{i+1}=s_{i}^n$

For example with $(2^5+1)/3 = 11$ and $(5 > 2)$ :

- $s_0$ = $5^2$ = $25$
- $s_1$ = $5^2$ mod $11 = 3$
- $s_2$ = $3^2$ mod $11 = 9$
- $s_3$ = $9^2$ mod $11 = 4$
- $s_4$ = $4^2$ mod $11 = 5$
- $s_5$ = $5^2$ mod $11 = 3$

Then $11$ is prime.

Another example with $(3^7-1)/2 = 1093$ :

- $s_0$ = $7^3$ = $343$
- $s_1$ = $7^3$ mod $1093 = 343$
- $s_2$ = $343^3$ mod $1093 = 47$
- $s_3$ = $47^3$ mod $1093 = 1081$
- $s_4$ = $1081^3$ mod $1093 = 458$
- $s_5$ = $458^3$ mod $1093 = 491$
- $s_6$ = $491^3$ mod $1093 = 1057$
- $s_7$ = $1057^3$ mod $1093 = 343$

Then $1093$ is prime

Another exemple with a composite number $(3^5-1)/2$ = $121$

- $s_0$ = $5^3$ = $125$
- $s_1$ = $5^3$ mod $121 = 4$
- $s_2$ = $4^3$ mod $121 = 64$
- $s_3$ = $64^3$ mod $121 = 58$
- $s_4$ = $58^3$ mod $121 = 60$
- $s_5$ = $60^3$ mod $121 = 15$

$121$ is not prime because 4 =/= 15

Is there a way to explain that ? I don't know how to start for proving it.

Comment: Did you write $R_q$ instead of $R_p$ in your criterion?

Comment: Indeed this is a mistake I will edit that Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem? Have you heard about Fermat pseudoprimes?

Comment: The condition $s_0\equiv s_p\pmod {R_p}$ is equivalent to $p^{n(n^p-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{R_p}$. Therefore, this test is weaker than the Fermat test to base $p$, at least in the case $R_p=(n^p-1)/(n-1)$.

Comment: How widely have you tested this? It shouldn't take more than a couple of hours to code up a test that'll hit, say, all $R_p$ less than a billion or so; any number in that range has $n\leq 9$, and so there are fewer than $(9-2)\cdot(\log_2{10^9})\approx 240$ cases to check.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician but I know a little the two theorem. Can you give me a counterexample if you have one ? Thanks

Comment: Small correction:  as your examples indicate, I think you mean to write $s_1 = p^n$, not $s_1 = s_0^n = (p^n)^n$.

Comment: @Mastrem The only concern I have with "this test is weaker than", is that Fermat's test applies to all numbers. For this specific case of numbers of this particular form, we might be able to get by with testing a smaller subset. Of course, it's unlikely that just testing 1 will work (so finding a counterexample should be relatively easy)

Comment: CalvinLin just gave you a counterexample. In general, this will fail often for $R_p=(n^p+1)/(n+1)$ and $n$ odd.

Comment: This is another mistake but it works with (3^5+1)/4 for me. I think I made a mistake as Ravi Fernando mentionned

Comment: @kijinSeija Ah k, I miscalculated.

Comment: Can you clarify Ravi's comment? It does seem like you use $s_1 = p^n$.

Comment: Correcting the error I mentioned, this test is equivalent to $p^{n^p - n} \equiv 1 \pmod{R_p}$.  Since $n^p - n$ is a multiple of $R_p - 1$ in both cases, this is (as @Mastrem said) weaker than the Fermat test to base $p$.  In particular, it will always be correct when $R_p$ is prime (like 61), and may only have counterexamples in the opposite direction (i.e. pseudoprimes).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for all the mistake, Don't hesitate to edit if you found another error. I will try with pseudoprimes

Comment: @CalvinLin yes but I noticed than p>n but 3 is not superior to 5

Comment: $p=5$,$n=4$, $(4^5-1)/(4-1)=341$  is a counter example

Comment: Indeed 341 is a counterexample, thanks !